# Get one of each

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Get one of each result returned by a `foreach`.

### The scenario

Take a look in the follow Razor's code fragment:

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Collection.Products)
{
    <p>@product.name</p>
}
```

The return to the client is:

> Xbox 360
>
> Xbox 360
>
> Xbox 360
>
> Xbox 360
>
> Playstation 3
>
> Playstation 3
>
> Playstation 3

Now, let me explain: my application compares the price of products in different stores. In my case, there are Xbox 360 in four stores while Playstation 3 exists in three stores — that's why their names repeat.

What I want is simple: get the name of each product just one time to fill a HTML's table column — can you all understand?

### Philosophy

Each product is added on Session. In our case, there are two products on session — the first one is `Xbox 360` and the second is `Playstation 3`. So, as you can see I can use Session to work with this *("for each item on Session, do something...")*, but I think it isn't necessary because invariably I'll have to run a query on the database and, by logic, its returns me what I need. In other words, **I do not need to use the Session except to temporarily store what the users need.**

### Spotlight

The `Model.Collection.Products` is of type `List<Products>`.

### What do I tried?

Something like this:

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Collection.Products.FirstOrDefault())
{
    [...]
}
```

But, of course, unsuccessful. Basically I need something like `FirstOfEach()`.

Comment: What a nice formatted question! Kudos!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The Solution**

Use a [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx)...

```
@foreach (var group in Model.Collection.Products.GroupBy(x => x.name))
{
    <p>@group.Key</p>
}
```

A `GroupBy` will return an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` where the `Key` property represents the value of the property you are grouping by (in this case: `name`)

---

**Other Benefits**

The benefit of this approach is that you can also access the items for each group, so if you wanted to list the different prices for each group, for example, you could do something like this:

```
@foreach (var group in Model.Collection.Products.GroupBy(x => x.name))
{
    <p>Product: @group.Key (@group.Count() items)</p>
    <p>Prices: 
    @foreach(var item in group)
    {
        <span>@item.price</span>
    }
    </p>
}
```

(I know this isn't the best HTML, it's just an example of usage!)

Comment: I think this is the most flexible as it allows uniqueness per property AND give him the opportunity to access all the elements within the group as well.

Comment: WOW! Very complete and well explained answer! Thanks, musefan. You solved my problem.

Comment: Hey, Musefan... Just one more question: and what if I want to GroupBy `name` and `price`, for example? I did this: `@foreach (var item in Model.Collection.Products.GroupBy(p => new { p.productName, p.quantity }))`, but now the loop is showing all results instead of distinct.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge: If it is showing all results then I would expect that you do not have any results that have both the same name AND the same price

Answer (score 7):

You need `DistinctBy`

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Collection.Products.DistinctBy(p=>p.name))
```

---

```
public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        return source.Where(x => knownKeys.Add(keySelector(x)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the distinct product names you can extract a distinct list from the collection:

```
@foreach (var productName in Model.Collection.Products.Select(p=>p.Name).Distinct())
{
    <p>@productName</p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement this in conjunction with

```
foreach (var product in Model.Collection.Products.Distinct())
```

and

```
public class Products : IEquatable<Products>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }  //your properties

    public bool Equals(Products other)
    {

        //Check whether the compared object is null. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal. 
        return Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null. 
        int hashProductName = Name == null ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode();  


        //Calculate the hash code for the product. 
        return hashProductName ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to GroupBy you can also convert your list to Lookup

```
Model.Collection.Products.ToLookup(x => x.name))
```